# Hit An Action Only Once In Controller RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been learning RoR and I've found myself wondering how to accomplish a user only being able to "roll" one time (essentially - accessing an action in a controller ONE time). Let me explain.

People join a pool, an array is made of user_ids in the pool.  "Roll" randomly selects one user ID from the pool, and then displays the name of the user associated with that user_id.

I would like to make sure that user is saved, and they couldn't just hit the back arrow on the browser and "roll" again.

I've seen some solutions that "disable" links via javascript, but I don't think that's the solution I'm looking for. I'd much rather have a more secure server-side storage of the original user_id.

What would be a way of accomplishing this?  I will post my code.
Here is the controller with the show actions and the roll.

```
def show
  @pool = Pool.find_by_id(params[:id])   
  @games = Game.where(params[:pool_id])    
end

def roll
  @pool = Pool.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
  @entrants = []
  games = @pool.games
  ids = games.each do |game|
    @entrants << game.user_id
  end
  @loserwiner = @entrants.sample
  puts @loserwiner
end
```

Here is how I access the roll from the view.

```
<%= link_to "Roll", {:controller => 'pools', :action => "roll"}%>
```

I'm assuming I could use some conditional logic to determine whether or not the action has been accessed... but I'm not sure of how...

Thanks for the help guys! Much appreciated.

Comment: Also feel free to just link me some reading material, I realize I'm not even that close to the solution and I'm not trying to be spoon-fed!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm

Comment: Not an answer, but your `roll` method is *extremely* unidiomatic. It could be literally one line: `@loserwinner = Pool.find(params[:id]).games.map(&:user_id).sample`. Unless you actually need the intermediate variables (`@pool`, `@entrants`) you should remove them; You should use `find(id)` never `find_by_id(id)`; You should learn to prefer `map` to translate one array into another instead of `each`.

Comment: @meagar `pluck` is actually better than `map` here.

Answer (score 1):

Every time someone joins the pool you want to display a loser? Are other users also supposed to see this loser, or is it per player?

You can store the info in the session:

```
session[@pool.id] = @loserwiner
```

So you'd just have to check that `session[@pool.id]` is present at the beginning of the action.

Or if you want to persist this information, you can create a join table between `user` and `pool` with a column storing the loser. Then it's easy to check if the user already rolled for this pool.

---

Details:

Instead of this:

```
@entrants = []
games = @pool.games
ids = games.each do |game|
  @entrants << game.user_id
end
```

You can write

```
@entrants = @pool.games.pluck(:user_id)
```

And instead of

```
<%= link_to "Roll", {:controller => 'pools', :action => "roll"}%>
```

you probably want to use the named route

```
<%= link_to "Roll", roll_pool_path(pool) %>
```

Comment: Essentially people who are in the pool gets rolled and one of them loses (being selected is losing.) Everyone in the pool sees who loses.  Is session[] immune from a user deleting their cookies and then re-rolling?

Comment: and congrats on 10k =P

Comment: No, if you want to be **sure** they can't roll twice, you'll have to store the information elsewhere, in your db, or redis, whatever. (and thanks ;))